# XPath: get only elements with a certain subelement

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have a filesyste that is represented in an xml document in the following format:

```
<xml xmlns="namespace1" xmlns:ns2="namespace2">
  <entry>
    <id>123</id>
    <ns2:content name="type">directory</ns2:content>
    <ns2:content name="numErrors">3</ns2:content>
  </entry>
  ...
  <entry>
    <id>456</id>
    <ns2:content name="type">file</ns2:content>
    <ns2:content name="docState">success</ns2:content>
  </entry>
  ...
</xml>
```

What I need to do is, using Python's lxml, retrieve only the `entry` objects that represent directories.  All entries contain a `<ns2:content name="docState">` object, but I need to know how to retrieve a list of `entry` objects where that object's text is equal to `directory`.  I can do this in several inconvenient steps, but I would rather have one query for it.  Here is the way I would do it in steps:

```
#xml_parse.py

ns={'ns1':'namespace1','ns2':'namespace2'}
for node in tree.xpath("//ns1:entry",namespaces=ns):
    if node.find("ns2:content[@name='type']").text=="directory":
      #do stuff with node
      pass
```

Can anyone explain how to do this within the for statement instead of using an if?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following XPath expression:

```
//ns1:entry[ns2:content[@name='type' and .='directory']]
```